# Specification of an Bayesian Zero-One-Inflated Beta Regression

Tags: bayesian, brms

I have a large dataset in which people tuned sliders corresponding to features from -1 to 1. The data distribution has large amounts of data at the extrema so I decided to model a zero-one-inflated beta regression using brms.

I want to predict the shape of distribution and then use the expected posterior draws to scan for differences between choices that were made earlier in the task. I am primarily following this guide: https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2021/11/08/beta-regression-guide/#special-case-1-zero-one-inflated-beta-regression

My formula is basically:

`y <- brm(bf(x ~ Choice, phi ~ Choice, zoi ~ Choice,   coi ~ Choice), prior = set_prior(paste("normal(0,1)"), class = "b"), data = df, family = zero_one_inflated_beta(), iter = 1e4, chains = 4, cores = 4, backend = "cmdstanr" )`

y was rescaled to 0 - 1. Choices is a factor with 4 unordered levels.

I was specifically worried about the priors:
`b ~ normal(0,1) Intercept ~ student_t(3, 0, 2.5) Intercept_coi ~ logistic(0, 1) Intercept_phi ~ student_t(3, 0, 2.5) Intercept_zoi ~ logistic(0, 1)`

I dont have any strong presumptions about the data, because the setting is very unique. However, I dont want to make any crucial mistakes. Furthermore the dataset contains ~14,000 cases so I imagine that Priors are not super important.

Comment: The question is if there are any crucial statistical mistakes in my formula